# Merge the indexed-view tags

Tags: support, tags

The [indexed-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexed-view) and [indexed-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexed-views) tags have identical meaning. They would be better combined into a single [indexed-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexed-view) tag.

Comment: agree ..not only this tag many tags even on SO needs really to merge